# TypeError: can‘t pickle onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.InferenceSession objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, onnxruntime

I Using flask to provide model services, this problem is encountered when using multiple processes to speed up obtaining model results, then the model initialization method is also passed to the pool, but it takes time. How to initialize the model process pool when initializing the flask service？When calling the flask interface, pass parameters to the process pool to get the model results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.